# Estimate times when a product is regularly delivered to a shop

Tags: time-series, estimation

Just for curiosity: I buy one kind of bread in the mall I regularly visit. Every time I am there I see how many of them are on the shelf (unfortunately, very often none). I expect that the times during the week when they deliver it are the same every week (but the number and the times are unknown) and for simplicity, we can assume my visits are random.

So my data looks like:

```
 visit_time        count
 2018-01-01 16:52  2
 2018-01-01 18:00  0
 2018-01-05 10:30  0
 ...
 2020-01-06 12:40  5
```

The task is to guess what are the most probable times (or their probability density) during the week when the bread is delivered (so I will know when to go there). So, one possible solution could be: Monday 10:00 + Friday 13:00. Which statistical technique should I choose?